# Global unhandled rejection handler

Tags: javascript, promise, event-handling

I'm using https://github.com/rtsao/browser-unhandled-rejection for global unhandled rejections.

This is how handler is registered:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (params) => {

});
```

I'm not sure how should I handle promise in this `callback`? Everything is working correctly and this handler is invoked every time `promise` fails and `catch` is not implemented so I'm getting `'Uncaught (in promise)'`.

Is there a way to handle failed promise inside `unhandledrejection` so it does not throw `'Uncaught (in promise)'` error and that code where `promise` failed continue normally as if `catch` was implemented? In `params` argument I have access to rejected `promise` but I'm not sure how should I handle that or is it even possible?

Comment: No, the `unhandledrejection` event is not the place to handle an error. It's only purpose is for monitoring. To handle rejections properly, fix the code where you are using the promises, i.e. implement `catch` or whatever. An unhandled rejection should never occur in a correctly working program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specification, the event is cancellable, so you can add

```
params.preventDefault(); // Note: `params` here is more idiomatically called `event`
```

to your handler to prevent the default action. (This prevents the "Unhandled rejection" warning on Chrome, which implements this without that polyfill.)

Example **without** `preventDefault`:

```js
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
    console.log("Got the unhandledrejection event");
});
Promise.reject();
```

```html
Look in the real browser console.
```

Example **with** `preventDefault`:

```js
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
    console.log("Got the unhandledrejection event");
    event.preventDefault();
});
Promise.reject();
```

```html
Look in the real browser console.
```